How to solve Pandas/Numpy error in Python?
EDIT: Ok so the problem might be that I haven't removed the old python env when I updated with the new version.
I've seen that I do have a "C:\users...\Python311" and a "C:\users...\Python312" in PATH.
Should I just move the .exe files from Python311\Scripts to Python312\Scripts and just delete the Python 311 PATH?
I was trying to retrieve all the 4 digit characters under column A from an excel file.
Though running the program it gives the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\get tags.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas\_libs\interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

Tried uninstalling and installing both Numpy and Pandas but some Warning messages appear in the prompt and it says "already satisfied" while I've just uninstalled them, so it shouldn't.
Here is the prompt text:


C:\Users\Utente>pip uninstall pandas numpy
Found existing installation: pandas 2.2.2
Uninstalling pandas-2.2.2:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\pandas-2.2.2.dist-info\*
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\pandas.libs\msvcp140-ef6047a69b174ada5cb2eff1d2bc9a62.dll
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\pandas\*
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled pandas-2.2.2
Found existing installation: numpy 2.0.1
Uninstalling numpy-2.0.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy-2.0.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy-2.0.1.dist-info\*
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy.libs\libscipy_openblas64_-fb1711452d4d8cee9f276fd1449ee5c7.dll
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy.libs\msvcp140-8021418012832a07a8ca5105a33b1086.dll
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\*
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\scripts\f2py.exe
    c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\scripts\numpy-config.exe
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-2.0.1

C:\Users\Utente>pip install pandas numpy
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution ~umpy (C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution ~umpy (C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages)
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.2.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-2.0.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.9.0.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
Using cached pandas-2.2.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (11.5 MB)
Using cached numpy-2.0.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (16.3 MB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution ~umpy (C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas


It's difficult for anyone to answer this without seeing the code or data that caused the problem. However, you are encountering the error in one environment (Python 3.11) uninstalling and reinstalling pandas and numpy in a different environment (Python 3.12), so that's certainly not going to fix the problem.

Ok so the problem might be that I haven't removed the old python env when I updated with the new version?
I've seen and I do have a "C:\users...\Python311" and a "C:\users...\Python312".
Should I just move the .exe from Python311\Scripts to Python312\Scripts and just delete the Python 311 PATH?

Are you using a tool to manage different environments, or just one global environment? If you're only using one environment and no longer need the old one yes you can delete it from your path? It might be better in the long term to use a tool like venv which allows you to have multiple Python environments.

The error message suggests that you have a mismatch in some code package between one installation and another. And given that you have two installations it is possible that some code has been installed in the wrong place. Do not manually move anything from one place to another as that may just make the problem worse. I would remove both installations completely and start clean with a new Python and associated packages.

@SamR I don't use any tool to manage the envs. I'm not really knowledgeable on the subject, I just created the PATH once when I downloaded Python 2 years ago

@OldBoy yeah, i've seen that some were installed in the 311 and some in the 312. I've now deleted the PATH of the 311. What should I do know and how? sorry for the stupid question, I'm not really knowledgeble on the envs and how they work.

I agree with @OldBoy. Definitely don't move the exe files between versions. Once you remove Python 3.11, you might be able to get away with using 3.12. However, if not, just remove it and do a fresh install.

As I already suggested try removing both versions and starting afresh. If your existing (3.12) installation still has anything incorrectly installed than you may still have issues. Installing to a clean system will not take long and should ensure these problems are resolved.

Instead of installing dependencies on your system, be aware of environment tools (venv/conda/virtualenv) before setting up a Python project. They relief you from the burden of compatibility among dependencies of different projects. For each project, set up a different environment, activate it and that's it.
